# Why window or document can't be set to undefined or null?

Tags: javascript, browser

This might be a silly question but I haven't found an answer to it. Why can't we do the following?

```
window = undefined
```

OR

```
document = undefined
```

I know those are globals and are available in browsers but thinking of how JavaScript works, is it not possible? Are those re-evaluated every time we try to access them?

I am also interested in knowing how the `window` or `document` objects remain what they are even after setting them to a random value... may be a `number` or `undefined` or `null`.

Comment: I never thought about it, I'd assume that the interpreter simply disallows assigning values to these objects.

Comment: window is the CONTEXT of the executing javascript and its implementation is defined by the browser vendor, you should ask to mozilla devs. document is the dom object so guess what

Comment: I agree but it just seems like a hard-imposed restriction which isn't documented( or probably is but I don't know.) The effect remains the same even if I declare a variable with same name e.g. `var document`. If these are reserved somehow, the interpreter should throw errors.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#dom-window):

> The window attribute must return the `Window` object's browsing context's `WindowProxy` object.
>   The document attribute must return the `Window` object's newest `Document` object.

Meaning `window` is the context in which all of your scripts are evaluated. If it was writable then the above wouldn't hold and the implementation wouldn't follow the spec, therefore it isn't writable.
For similar reasons you can add properties to `document` but you can't override it.

You can verify this by looking at the IDL:

```
[Unforgeable] readonly attribute WindowProxy window;
[Unforgeable] readonly attribute Document document;
```

Comment: how about `document`?

Comment: after edit - so shouldn't it punish you by throwing errors in the console for the same.. "This browser won't let you bomb all of it.." or something similar.

Comment: @TheWarlock I can't recall off the top of my head if the spec defines whether writing to a readonly should fail silently or not.

Comment: Oddly enough, in Chrome `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "window")` does get you `{value: Window,` **`writable: true`** `, enumerable: true, configurable: false}`

Comment: I was just going to try that out... I am still not convinced at this. :(

Comment: @Bergi While it shows as writable (for whatever reason), assigning to it doesn't actually override it, so it seems it's still readonly internally, as the spec defines it.

Comment: @Bergi,  `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "document")` returns `writable : false`. Also, can you explain how adding a property to `window` or `document` is different from writing?

Comment: Update - in Firefox, `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(window, "document")`  does not seem to contain the `writable` key

Answer (score 1):

`window` is the context. You cant't do `this = something` else.
`document` is property of window. It is not writable or configurable.

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor( window, 'document' );
```

output

```
Object {value: document, 
   writable: false,
   enumerable: true, 
   configurable: false}
```

Comment: OP wouldn't do `this = something`, but `window = something`.

Comment: in the context of browser window it is the same

Comment: Yes, in the global scope both `window` and `this` refer to the same object. But they don't work the same, and that `this` is unassignable doesn't mean anything for the `window` variable.

Comment: Fun fact: `window` has a reference to itself. `window.window === window`

Comment: and that `window` has another `window` and so on... infinite windows within a window :O

Comment: @TheWarlock I believe it is circular reference, it refers to itself so it is the same object.